# Why does my program duplicate output when it should not?

Tags: c#, foreach, duplicates

My application basically takes a string of characters and counts how many times each of the alphabetic characters appears. It also ignores numbers being type. But it duplicates the same alphabets second time I input it.

Code:

```
string input = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();

while (input[0] != 'q') {
    int[] counting = new int[26];
    Array.Clear(counting, 0, counting.Length);

    //string to array conversion
    if (input.Length > 0 && input.ToUpper()[0] == 'Q')
        return;

    string all = ".";
    for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++) {
        bool checking = false;
        string number = "";

        for (int j = 0; j < input.Length; j++) {
            if (input.ToUpper()[i] == input.ToUpper()[j]) {
                number += input.ToUpper()[i];
            }
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < all.Length; j++) {
            if (input[i] == all[j]) {
                checking = true;
            }
        }
        all += input[i];
        if (!checking) {
            input = Regex.Replace(input, @ "[\d-]", string.Empty);
            Console.Write(number[0].ToString() + number.Length.ToString() + " ");
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine();

    input = Console.ReadLine();
```

It is supposed to only output "A6" which it did successfully the first time but stops on the second time.

Output:

```
aAaAaA
A6
aAaAaA
A6 A2
```

Comment: The first `Console.ReadLine().ToUpper()` does not match the second `Console.ReadLine()`.

Comment: Off topic: consider normalizing the input to upper if that's how you want it. As it is, you're creating unnecessary strings doing things like `x.ToUpper()[i] == x.ToUpper()[j]`.